# How to permanently allow access to a directory in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a new tab chrome extension and would like to permanently allow access to a directory after the user has provided permission.

So far I can get it to persist as long as the user does not close the tab.

For example, this confirms the permissions are all there.

```
async function saveDirectoryHandle(directoryHandle: FileSystemDirectoryHandle) {
    console.log({directoryHandle})
    const handlePermissionDescriptor = await directoryHandle.queryPermission({mode: 'readwrite'});
    if (handlePermissionDescriptor !== 'granted') {
        const requestPermissionDescriptor = await directoryHandle.requestPermission({mode: 'readwrite'});
        if (requestPermissionDescriptor !== 'granted') {
            throw new Error('Permission to access directory was not granted.');
        }
    }
    await storeHandle(directoryHandle)
}
```

But once I close all the new tabs and open another I get `Failed to execute 'requestPermission' on 'FileSystemHandle': User activation is required to request permissions.`

Is there a way around this?

Comment: There's no way as persistency for handles is not yet implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know where I can read about it?

Comment: https://github.com/WICG/file-system-access/issues/297